# Uploading a game in google play developer console

Tags: android

I published a game in the google play developer console and the state is published, but i have not upload any APK yet and i do not see the app uploaded to google play. Do I have to do something more?

Sorry for this question, is my first game and I do not know if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469

Comment: and https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/index.html